# Using stop mode in freeRTOS on a STM32L0 and waking up using EXTI interrupt

Tags: low-power, rtos, freertos, stm32l

I want to make a low power device, running freeRTOS.
There are 3 threads, which I planned to suspend normally into stop mode and resume execution depending on an EXTI interrupts.

I intended doing so by this Idle hook

```
void vApplicationIdleHook(){
    trace_printf("Enter Idle \n");
    HAL_PWR_EnterSTOPMode(PWR_LOWPOWERREGULATOR_ON, PWR_STOPENTRY_WFI);
}
```

Which should be woked up by this Interrupt

```
void initInterrupts(){
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_1_IRQn);
}

void EXTI0_1_IRQHandler(void) {
     __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(BTN_PIN);
     trace_printf("interrupt\n");
     xTaskResumeFromISR(thread_handle);
}
```

It's working so far, as my power consumption drops from 1.7mA to 1.5mA somehow I suppose, but I encounter two problems:

- that the RTOS doesn't seem to kick in anymore
- the debugger loses it's connection to the board

I do not know, what I am missing. Which are the general steps for enableing RTOS after entering the stop mode?

Concerning the debbuger connection, the print statement reaches it's way somehow to the PC, but openOCD complains by

```
Info : Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect 
Error: jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure 
Polling target stm32l0.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
```

I have set debbuging register as this, but it does not seem enough. Can I even hold the debugging bridge in stop mode? I mean the `DBGMCU_CR_DBG_STOP` bit makes me suppose yes, but what options have to be set therfore?

```
__DBGMCU_CLK_ENABLE();
DBGMCU->CR |= DBGMCU_CR_DBG_SLEEP_Msk | DBGMCU_CR_DBG_STOP_Msk | DBGMCU_CR_DBG_STANDBY_Msk;
```

For me it is very confusing, that the MCU still can send to the PC, but the openOCD fails resuming or holding the connection.

Thank you all to much for any hint.

Comment: First of all - as far as I know FreeRTOS has a feature called tickless idle, which stops the whole system and waits for interrupts. There are many demos of that feature on FreeRTOS website. The downside I think is that you need to keep track of time while the system is stopped, so you need some kind of low-power timer. Secondly - debuggers and low-power modes generally don't go along well :( Some chips will keep the debug module running in sleep, others won't. It can of course affect your measurements.

Comment: This comment, *"It's working so far, as my power consumption drops from 1.7mA to 1.5mA"*, worries me a lot. That's negligible. This tells me there is either a fundamental problem in FreeRTOS (as configured and compiled), or else a fundamental problem in your understanding about how to use it. If the processor is stopped, it should be stopped. Sometimes, it requires an external interrupt to wake it up. Sometimes, it permits a low-power timer to continue running for the purpose of generating a timer interrupt to wake things up. But in all my experience with other designs, current drops a lot.

Comment: I used tickless mode, which triggers the timer overflow only every 8 seconds, instead of every 1 ms before activating the tickless idle macro... For keep the debugging bridge I hoped setting the `DBGMCU_CR_DBG_STOP`bit would make that work, but it breaks one way (openOCD to MCU), the MCUs printf's still make it to the console... I also think the 1.7 to 1.5mA drop is negligible, but I suppose this comes from the broken debugger interface trying to keep up the connection again. But ya, I hoped someone else faced this kind of problem before and knows better what could be the issue of the setup ^^

Comment: Paul, most processors these days (and I assume by extension this applies to the STM32L0) include a way to shut themselves down to a very low power arrangement, either with *only* external interrupts enabled and no timer operating or else both external interrupts and a low power timer running. Either way, the OS should be able to use that hardware in just the way it was intended -- very low power. On some, this is nothing more than hitting a "HLT" instruction, which must then be interrupted but where the power is otherwise barely consumed while idle. It worries me this isn't easy in FreeRTOS.